# Salesforce SOQL return all partners of single account

Tags: api, salesforce, soql

I am trying to find all the account that have the same partner. I am new to SOQL and I cannot do a join so I am at a loss. Here is the closest I have gotten:

```
Select Name, Site, Status__c
FROM Account 
WHERE Account.Id = Partner.AccountToId 
AND Partner.AccountFromId = '0013000000bF5rtABC'
```

This does not work. Perhaps my brain is not functioning, but I just cant figure this out. I need to pull all of the account who are partners with '0013000000bF5rtABC' (or whatever account).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below query will return all accounts who are partners with 0013000000bF5rtABC. In salesforce you need to use concept of inner queries to perform join.

```
Select Name, Site, Status__c
FROM Account 
where ID IN 
(Select AccountToId from Partner where AccountFromId = '0013000000bF5rtABC')
```